# How can I update this Swift2 for-in loop without casting syntax to match Swift3's casting required syntax?

Tags: swift, swift3

So I'm tryin gto make the following code work under swift 3, but no matter what I try I just cause new errors.  I can't seem to figure out how to cast the dataArray object into anything that will pass.  (Original dev didn't type it, and it's always set via notification objects, making tracing it's *actual* data type down... difficult; best I can tell it's just a dictionary generated from server JSON via parsing)

```
var dataArray:NSMutableArray = []

func foo(_ notification: Notification)
{
    if let id = notification.object as? Int
    {
        for dataOut in dataArray where Int(dataOut["id"] as! Int) == id {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fooSegue", sender: dataOut)

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to compile this produces a syntax error about `Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members`.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Alexander a simple 'what data type is dataArray' would have been more helpful than an entire instruction page, since that's the only missing piece.

Comment: No, I don't just care about its type. First of all, knowing its `NSMutabeArray` doesn't tell me anything at all about its contents. I also would like a mock, ... a minimal, **COMPLETE**, verifiable example, so I have a concrete problem to work with, rather than having to guess what I think you might be working with.

Comment: @Alexander you've got exactly what problem I've got then.  Issue being that I can't *find* what data types are shoved in there; it's all done by notifications.  And never cast into something useful.  As far as I can tell, it's just dictionaries.  Which is stupid, but it's what I'm stuck with.

Comment: So print the data structure, `dump` it, give us *something* to work with.

Comment: @Alexander I can't print or dump it; code won't run because it's invalid syntax.  I finally managed to track down where the data is set though... I think, anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133501/discussion-between-alexander-and-ronlugge).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a necessary reason why `dataArray` is of type `NSMutableArray`? If I were receiving some kind of `Array` object which I assert to contain elements of a `Dictionary` type, I would do the following:

```
if let id = id as? Int,
    let data = dataArray as NSArray as? [[String:Any]]
{
    for element in data where Int(element["id"] as! Int) == id
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fooSegue", sender: element)
        return
    }
}
```

Edited to cast `dataArray` from `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray` to `[[String:Any]]` and subscript `element` instead of `data`.

Comment: Original dev made it a mutable array because he pulls and pushes data into it pretty often.

Comment: Regardless, casting it to [[String:Any]] in this instance shouldn't matter since you aren't making any modifications to the array within the `for` loop.

Comment: FYI, the syntax on this doesn't work; getting errors about the guard condition needing an else, and element declared in guard not available in it's body...

Comment: You're right; that was supposed to be an `if` not a `guard` @RonLugge

Comment: So `cast from NSMutableArray to unrelated type '[[String : Any]]' always fails` is throwing an error on casting, and `Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'`.

Comment: Let me run a Playground snippet